# Angular 4.3 HttpClient GET with Type

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I have the following service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExerciseService {

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

    public getExercises(): Observable<Exercise> {
        return this.http.get<Exercise>('http://localhost:8090/exercise/1');
    }
}

interface Exercise {
    name: string;
}
```

What I get from this call is this:

> { defaultValue: 10, id: 1, name "string" }

But because I am passing a type to my call I expected to only get the name back from this function. 
I'm just getting started with Angular 4 and I don't see what's wrong :/

Comment: Type casting the get() will not delete properties from the server response.

Comment: Then what exactly does this do? Because the way I see it now it doesn't change anything when I add this. I thought it would parse it to the given interface.

Comment: If you wanted to work with the properties on the returned object, without the type casting you'd have to access them via something like bracket notation `data['someProperty']` to keep the TypeScript compiler from throwing errors, or manually cast it at some point. As Lazar Ljubenović as has stated in his answer, if you want to change the shape of the data before it's `subscribe()` somewhere, you can take advantage of `map()` and other RxJS operators. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types in TypeScript are static compile-time hints to the compiler (and possibly your IDE) to help you while writing code. Your server cannot know about the specified type and will return the same data as always. It doesn't even know it that code has been written in TypeScript when it was called.

Use `map` to manually transform the response if you need it or implement a different endpoint.

Comment: As I understood the 'map' was no longer used in the new HttpClient in Angular 4.3 because the default ParseType was JSON. That's why I thought passing the type would parse the result into that type and then passing it to the controller where the service is used.

Comment: @JeroenDierckx you are correct, the httpClient assumes the response will be json unless told otherwise (no longer need .json). However it does not make assumptions on what properties should be parsed. Lazar is recommending something like `.map(res => {return {name: res.name}})` to return an object with just the name property

Comment: Lazar and LLai, thank you for the explanation and the clarification. It all makes way more sense now!